# Question regarding result of "No late binding for static methods" [Java]

Tags: java, oop, methods, static, polymorphism

Given the code from Parent class and Child class:

```
class Parent{

   public static void classMethod(){
      System.out.println("ClassMethod in Parent"); 
   }

   public void hello(){
      System.out.println("Hello from parent, call classMethod");
      classMethod();
   }
}
```

```
class Child extends Parent{

   public static void classMethod(){
      System.out.println("ClassMethod in Child"); 
   } 

}
```

If I have this in main method:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
   Parent D = new Child(); 
   D.hello();
}
```

Why is this the result? ->

```
Hello from parent, call classMethod 
ClassMethod in Parent
```

So there's a child object of parent class calling an instance method which calls a static method.
I would understand why it calls the static method from the parent class if hello() was static as well, since the object type would be defined at compile time and it would be Parent. However, since hello() here is an instance method, it has to be resolved at runtime, and at runtime, isn't the type of the object the actual type, AKA Child type? So in that case, wouldn't it call the static method from the child object since the object is of child type at run time?

Answer (score 1):

Note: this answer assumes the `Child` class `extends Parent`. Otherwise, the code in the main method just throws an error.

This is an example of up-casting and polymorphism. Because it's of the type `Parent`, its access is limited to the `Parent` class. When you call the `hello()` method, it is being called in the `Parent` class. Then, this method calls `classMethod()` but, because `hello()` is a method in the parent class, it calls it in the `Parent` class as well, which is why you are getting that as a result. The fact that it is static makes no difference: static methods can always be called by instance methods, but not always the other way around.

One thing I should point out is that, because of the line `Parent D = new Child();`, the object `D` does not actually have access to any of the static methods in `Child` even though it is that type. If you wish for `D` to have access to methods in both `Parent` and `Child`, you can use `Child D = new Child();`

With `Parent D = new Child();`, if you are calling a method, it must be in the Parent class and will run the method in the parent class - except for if there is an overriding instance method of the same name in the Child class, in which case it will run this method instead. It should also be noted that an overridden method cannot be static

Comment: Thanks. When you say access is limited to the Parent class, do you mean completely? Because in my lecture notes it says that if D.instanceMethod() is called, even though D is declared of Parent class, it will be the instanceMethod() in the child class that is called because instance methods are resolved at runtime, and at runtime it will be the actual type of the object (child and not parent).

Comment: @HelloWorld here's a more concise explanation for this scenario: if you are calling a method, it must be in the Parent class and will run the method in the parent class - except for if there is an overriding instance method of the same name in the Child class, in which case it will run this method instead. I'm editing this into my answer

Comment: So, whenever a static method is called by an object, it's always going to be the static method from the class of the compile time type of the object?